# How to delete duplicates if all the their linked values in another table (foreign key linked rows) are also the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, duplicates, outer-join

I have three tables:

---

x (column1,..., x_id)

---

y (column1, column2, colum3, ..., x_id, y_id)

---

z (column1, column2, colum3,..., x_id, y_id, z_id)

My final goal: delete duplicates in y table if all of their linked values (based on foreign keys) in z table are also exactly the same.
For example, This is just an example.

For more clarification consider this example:
y table: my table structure is very similar to this and this table is close to the reality of what I have.

| column 1 | column 2 | x_id | y_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **foo** | **bar** | **1** | **1** |
| **foo** | **bar** | **1** | **2** |
| xx | yy | 2 | 3 |
| zz | kk | 2 | 4 |
| tt | mm | 2 | 5 |
| **baz** | **qux** | **3** | **6** |
| **baz** | **qux** | **3** | **7** |

has two groups with the same column 1 and column 2 and x_id values (the y_ids = (1 and 2) and y_id == (6,7).

Then for these rows, I want to check a second table to see if all the items are the same. meaning they have the same items in the z table. The items of the y_id = 1 and y_id = 2 are the same, so one of them in the y table should be deleted.

| {color:red;} column 1 | column 2 | column | x_id | y_id | z_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **foo** | **bar** | **qux** | **1** | **1** | **1** |
| **foo2** | **bar2** | **qux2** | **1** | **1** | **2** |
| **foo** | **bar** | **qux** | **1** | **2** | **3** |
| **foo2** | **bar2** | **qux2** | **1** | **2** | **4** |
| baz | foo | qux | 3 | 6 | 5 |
| baz2 | foo2 | qux1 | 3 | 6 | 6 |
| baz3 | foo3 | qux2 | 3 | 6 | 7 |
| baz | foo | qux | 3 | 7 | 8 |
| baz2 | foo2 | qux1 | 3 | 7 | 9 |

I want to delete the row with y_id = 1 from the y table ( or y_id = 2, which duplicate row doesn't make a difference). The tables are very big so a fast solution would be great. I know I can join the tables, but I was hoping I could find another solution. A solution that can use the group by IDs instead and just look for the found items there inside the z table (third table)

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: I want to delete one instance of duplicates, but not only based on the first table columns, after duplicates are found there, check for their items in table z and then see if the query result based on the ids are actually the same (the second comparison also is done based on certain columns). I don't know how to put those ids I have in the first group in the query that checks for the duplicates in the second table.

Comment: Put them in a temp table?

Comment: @DaleK Okay. But I need to know what I should compare with each other. I want to check the ones that are in the same group as the group found in the y table. so for example check the y_id = 1 and y_id = 2 and then then check y_id = 7 and y_id = 6 and so on. How can I define they belong to the same group? should I add another column for that? and then how to use them for comparison query in the z table? I'm very confused about this.

Comment: TBH I'm confused also... your question is more complicated than I have time to investigate.

Comment: I think you should have used more concrete (less abstract) example to improve our understand of the problem. Anyways, what is stopping you from joining all 3 tables together (on all the columns you need) and then doing a `GROUP BY` or [`ROW_NUMBER() OVER( [partition] )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to identify duplicates? If table size is a problem, use temporary tables, e.g. copy a subset of data to temp tables and use them for analisys. (There is no efficient solution for finding dups across tables)

Comment: If you have a lot of columns to compare you may think about using `HASHBYTES` function to generate a single hash for all of your columns in a row and then compare hashes.

Comment: @Alex, because that's exactly what I want to do! just different values. And yes the tables are really big. millions of records in one. and if you can give me an example of how to do it that would be great.

Comment: I am struggling to understand exactly what you want and I have read your question a few times over.

Comment: @Alex I really don't think I am asking for something that hard. If we have three tables x y z, group the y records based on the foreign key of x inside y table, and in each group check if they have duplicates, if they do, then we want to check z table, in which we have the y foreign keys, so based on y keys of those duplicates in z, check if they have exactly the same items in z. like if we have a list for each, regardless of order, the items are the same. that means they are complete duplicates. but if they have different items in z they just have similar names in y table.

Comment: @Alex There are usually paired duplicates in each group in y table if there are any, so we can easily compare them. Anyway, I found a solution myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the below example will help me to delete the rows I want:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        a.column1 AS a_column1,
        a.column2 AS a_column2,
        a.y_id AS a_y_id,
        a.x_id AS a_x_id,
        b.column1 AS a_column1,
        b.colum2 AS a_column2,
        b.y_id AS b_y_id ,
        b.x_id AS b_x_id 
    FROM YTable a
    JOIN YTable b
    ON a.column1 = b.column1 
        AND a.column2 = b.column2 
        AND a.x_id = b.x_id 
        AND a.y_id != b.y_id
    WHERE a.y_id < b.y_id
)
SELECT
    cte.*,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM (
                SELECT * FROM ZTable
                WHERE y_id = cte.y_id
            ) table1
            FULL JOIN (
                SELECT * FROM ZTable
                WHERE y_id = cte.y_id
            ) table2
            ON table1.colum1 = table2.column1
                AND table1.colum2 = table2.colum2
                AND table1.colum3 = table2.colum3
            WHERE table1.column1 IS NULL OR table2.column1 IS NULL
        )
        THEN 'Not Identical'
        ELSE 'Identical'
    END AS duplicated
FROM cte;
```